# insert on duplicate key update if

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I've done a lot of research on this and came up with the following:

```
INSERT INTO actives
SELECT email, active_date
FROM actives_ac
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active_date = IF (
    active_date < VALUES(active_date), VALUES(active_date), active_date
);
```

which results in, `SQL Error (1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

`email` field `VARCHAR(255)` is both a `KEY` and `UNIQUE` in both tables.
`active_date` is a `DATE` field.

I am trying to insert a record if it is new in actives table or, update record if the value in `actives_ac.active_date` is newer than the value already in `actives.active_date`.

Comment: It's telling you the number of columns isn't the same between the tables you're using. Show us your db structure

Comment: How many fields does `actives` have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just simply means that the number of values you want to insert doesn't match the total number of columns on the table. Try to be more explicit by specifying the columns where the values will be inserted, example,

```
INSERT INTO actives (email, active_date)
SELECT email, active_date 
FROM actives_ac
.....
```

Note: The reason why you are doing that is because you have a column which was set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed, right?

Comment: the query will execute if you pass `NULL` value for the `ID`, example,  `INSERT INTO actives 
SELECT NULL, email, active_date....`

Comment: Correct query:
    INSERT INTO actives (email, active_date) SELECT email,active_date FROM actives_ac ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE actives.active_date = IF (actives_ac.active_date < actives.active_date, actives.active_date, actives_ac.active_date);